# App Engine Module Logs Blank

Tags: google-app-engine, module, gae-module

I have a module in app engine configured like this:

```
application: app_name_goes_here
module: static-backend
version: uno
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: B2

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 10
  idle_timeout: 5m

env_variables:
   GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- appstats: off

inbound_services:
- channel_presence

handlers:

- url: /_ah/channel/connected/
  script: ChannelApi.app

- url: /_ah/channel/disconnected/
  script: ChannelApi.app

- url: /_ah/start
  script: ModuleStartup.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
- name: setuptools
  version: "0.6c11"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: '2.3'
- name: django
  version: "1.5"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest

skip_files:
- ([^\s]+(\.(?i)(less))$)
```

When looking at the logs I am seeing this:

[image]

The same logging is working fine inside the main app that isn't a backend module. I am logging using by defining my logger as log = logging.getLogger(**name**) and using log.info("Hello World!"). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a log viewer problem (or some not so intuitive feature?), happening if you select "All logs" (or "activity", showing in some cases) in the 2nd dropdown list above the logs table.

Logs show OK (i.e. the usual way) if you select "request_log" instead:

[image]

From [the viewer interface description](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer?hl=en_US&_ga=1.18759993.1484861412.1422834776#the_viewer_interface) it appears the dropdown is called "Log Selector" and from [this description](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer?hl=en_US&_ga=1.18759993.1484861412.1422834776#select_the_logs_you_want) it appears it is Compute Engine related and shouldn't show up on the App Engine logs viewer :)