# How can I view Log statements in Google Developers Console for a deployed GAE project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I know that when you run a Google App Engine project locally you can view Log statements in your API methods:

`log.warning("Some warning because you did something");`

But can you view those logs for a deployed project? When I go to `Logging` in the google developers console I can see logs for various actions of my API but I cannot see my custom logs I put into my methods like the one above.

I am using Java.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860951/app-engine-module-logs-blank/34861602#34861602

Comment: @DanCornilescu That is what I have it set on currently - no luck.

Comment: @DanCornilescu see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into `logging.properties` in my project and change:

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING
```

to

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = INFO
```

Now it works. Not sure why though.

Comment: Hm, are you by any chance using Java? If so it probably makes sense. From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/#Java_writing_application_logs: "Notice that the default log level in logging.properties is WARNING, which suppresses INFO messages from the output. To change the log level for all classes in your app, edit the logging.properties file to change the level. For example you could change .level = WARNING to .level = INFO."

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes. I am using Java. Thank you for finding the doc on that!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. Though I suggest using one of these two:

- Use google's logging library which will write logs for you and they will be available in log viewer and you can export them to your cloud storage or use them as pub/sub events. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/libraries
- If you just want your logs to be visible in the log viewer, another alternative is to use a logging library which writes the logs to `syslog` (http://www.networkmanagementsoftware.com/what-is-syslog/) and use `google-fluentd` on your instance. This will collect your custom logs as well as any other event logs to the log viewer.